# How To Create Custom User Role in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have to create a Reviewer (custom) role for users in WordPress , how can I create a custom rule ?

Comment: First of all I want to advise you to ask questions more clearly and try to do some search before you ask here and [wordpress.stackexchange.com](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) is the better for `WordPress` related questions.

Comment: Should be on wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use [add role](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_role/) function like

```
<?php add_role( $role, $display_name, $capabilities ); ?>
```

Example

```
add_role('basic_contributor', 'Basic Contributor', array(
    'read' => true, // True allows that capability
    'edit_posts' => true,
    'delete_posts' => false, // Use false to explicitly deny
));
```

Also [<s>see this tutorial (custom rule discussed)</s>](http://camwebdesign.com/techniques/wordpress-create-custom-roles-and-capabilities/) and [<s>this plugin too if you don't want to write any code.</s>](http://www.im-web-gefunden.de/wordpress-plugins/role-manager/)

Comment: Better call this on plugin activation hook, because this setting is saved to the database (in table wp_options, field wp_user_roles).

Comment: The site for the plugin is no longer active.

Comment: Thanks, striked it out @HighlyIrregular :-)

Answer (score 4):

If you're not looking to write a lot of code, but want to use a plugin then I highly recommend Justin Tadlock's Members plugin: https://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/

It should easily offer the functionality you seek.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use plugin so You can add/edit capability for specific users too.
There are 2 good plugins available

[User Role Editor](http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor)

and

[Capability Manager Enhanced](http://wordpress.org/plugins/capability-manager-enhanced)

Answer (score 0):

You can delete WordPress Default User Roles and create your own.

From your WordPress Admin Panel.
Navigate to:

> Appearance > Editor > (Choose Your Theme) > Theme functions

```
add_role('newbie', __(
 'Newbie'),
 array(
 'read' => true, // Allows user to read
 'create_posts' => true, // Allows user to create new posts
 'edit_posts' => true, // Allows user to edit their own posts
 )
);
```

[Source](http://www.cloudways.com/blog/add-custom-user-roles-in-wordpress/)